# I want to insert two values into a same table of sql, the first value is from another table and other value is argv[2]?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert two values into the same table of SQL. The first value comes from another table and the other value is argv[2].

This is the code that I am using but it does not work.

```
 for($i=0;$i<=feof($getdata);$i++){
    if (filter_var($data[$i][1], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        //echo $data[$i][1];
        $email=$data[$i][1];
        $type=$argv[2];
        $name=$data[$i][0];
        $sql ="INSERT INTO promo_user (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        $sql ="INSERT INTO promo_type set uid =$uid";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO promo_type (type) values ('$type')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Are you sure you do not confuse promo_type  table ? Because you insert into that table twice.

suggestions
1. use placeholders,
2. check errors after each query (better to use some DB library, or wrap mysqli functions by your library code)

Comment: The third insert part is not working.                                                                    $sql = "INSERT INTO promo_type (type) values ('$type')";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);